How do you create a PS1 variable that starts on the first line but has a second line?
I have recently moved to Linux on my computer, and my bash terminal just looks dull. I customized the PS1 variable in the .bashrc, but that still didn't help. I want to be able to put a more interesting prompt in, such as this:
Hello <Username>: <command input here>
You are in <current folder> on <computer> 

Is it possible to have the input on the first line and have the text on the second line? If so, how?

Do you just mean storing two lines of text in a variable, or including a line break in a string in a variable? What research have you done regarding this and what have you tried so far?

@music2myear I mean when you have a line break in the bash promt using \n is it possible to put the inupt on the first line? I haven't found anything for it online yet and I can't think how to do it.

Did you try it? That seems a pretty simple thing to just try. Did you do any searching of the internet prior to asking here? I'd guess whether this can be done and how are pretty well documented things.

I did try, but I seemingly couldn't find any infomation online.
